# Returning last element of a list in drracket

Tags: list, recursion, racket, element

I need help with my computer science homework. I've been trying to return the last element of a list but I keep failing. This is what I have so far:

```
(check-expect (last empty) "Error! The list is empty!")
(check-expect (last (list "apple" "banana" "pear" "orange")) "orange")

(define (last loe)
  (cond
    [(empty? loe) "Error! The list is empty!"]
    []))
```

I do not know where to go from here. I know i am missing a base case but i cannot figure it out. please help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`last`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._last%29%29) procedure is already included in Racket, you don't need to implement it. But if you have to write it from scratch it's a simple matter of knowing *where* to stop - right before the list ends! like this:

```
(define (last loe)
  (cond
    [(empty? loe) "Error! The list is empty!"] ; we don't allow empty lists
    [(empty? (rest loe)) (first loe)]          ; stop right before last
    [else (last (rest loe))]))                 ; advance recursion
```

Comment: This helped me so much! I appreciate the help!

Answer (score -1):

(define (last loe)
(if(null? loe)loe)
(car(reverse loe))))

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: And you might enjoy the [tour] and the helpful formatting info https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help